# SQL - Returning a range of numbers 1 to 1.99

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

For example:

700 means 700.00 - 700.99

400.1 means 400.10 - 400.19

Currently I have something like this:

```
Select codes 
From code_table
where codes in ('700', '400.1')
```

which doesn't  work because it's just looking for 700 and 400.1 so I tried:

```
Select codes 
From code_table
where left (codes, 3) = '700'
```

which works but the problem is my initial set of numbers I'm looking for is a lot more than just the 2 here, is there a simpler way to do this without having to do it for each one? I think the between clause can also work but also requires code each one?

Comment: do you have the list of number ranges stored in a table? If not, where are they coming from?

Comment: So you would *not* want your query to return a row where codes is 700.999?

Comment: +1 For a nice puzzler

Comment: @GoatCO the numbers are stored in a column with a bunch of other numbers.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' Yes, it should just go back to the 100th digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your comments correctly, you need to build the regular expressions explicitly if you compare against the varchar() values, or use strings with the BETWEEN operator.

So, this . . .

```
select * 
from code_table
where codes = '700' 
   or codes like '700.[1-9]' 
   or codes like '700.[1-9][0-9]';
```

or this.

```
select * 
from code_table
where codes between '700' and '700.99'
```

The second one is simpler. Both queries exclude the value '700.999', which I *believe* you want to exclude.

To work with numbers instead of varchar() values, cast to decimal. (*Not* to float.)

```
select * 
from code_table
where cast(codes as decimal(10, 3)) between 700 and 700.99;
```

In any case, your SQL has to know something about the structure of the codes. If I were in your position, I'd just pass the range explicitly. That way, the full responsibility is with the front-end code, so there shouldn't be any surprises.

Comment: From this answer, there doesn't look like there is a simple way of doing this. My colleague just suggested that I create a table outside of SQL with the needed numbers and use what I did in method 1 in the initial question.

Comment: The simplest way *might* be to use a table, but I'd rather have the table stored in the database. That way all applications could use it without duplication (and without error).

Answer (score 0):

You could cast to a number and test against your range, e.g.

```
Select codes 
From code_table
where cast (codes as float) >= 700 and
      cast (codes as float) < 700.1
```

Answer (score 0):

[FLOOR](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/arithmetic-functions/floor-wth-positive-value.php)()

```
SELECT codes FROM code_table WHERE FLOOR(codes) IN (..., ..., ...)
```

But you need decimals. So how about simply:

```
SELECT codes FROM code_table WHERE codes LIKE '700.%' OR codes LIKE '400.1%'
```

That's for standard SQL. For smarter solution, I'd either pick that `(... AS float)`, but codes tend to get more complex over time, like `700.1.10` or `700.19b`. So I'd perhaps create a stored procedure.

Comment: I think this is going to have to do...Until I run into more issues lol. Thanks.

Comment: Both those queries will return 700.999. They shouldn't, according to the OP's comments following the question.

Comment: This didn't work for me so I unchecked the answer. I will still be up to trying others if there are any others. I tried the other answers listed and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are actually working with text and text prefixes (that unfortunately happen to look like numbers and are causing confusion)

SELECT codes FROM code_table WHERE codes LIKE '700'+'%'

SELECT codes FROM code_table WHERE codes LIKE '400.1'+'%'

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

```
select * 
from code_table
where codes like '700.__' or codes like '400.1_'
```

Or to be sure to take only numeric values :

```
select * 
from code_table
where (codes like '700.__' or codes like '400.1_') and isnumeric(codes) = 1
```

Comment: Using __ instead of % will exclude 700.999

Comment: I tried this and this actually excluded some of the data which should've been a part of the result table.

Comment: Without having your data, it's hard to say what I can do to be sure to catch them all. With my test data, it's working fine. Can you give me an example of number that is not catch but need to? Thanks!